# Does β-hydride elimination in main group metals occur?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

As a side reaction of Grignard reagents, the following reaction is introduced on the Internet.
I think this is β-hydride elimination reaction, but magnesium is a main group metal, not a transition metal.
Does β-hydride elimination reaction in main group metals occur?
[image]

Comment: It rather looks like it.  If anything, magnesium as an alkaline earth metal makes the alpha-carbon more anionic than it would be with a transition metal; thus a more powerful nucleophile for displacing the hydride ion.