Correct mechanism of nucleophilic attack on sterically hindered carbonyl compound

I proposed the first mechanism while my friend proposed the second mechanism

Classic nucleophilic attack be carbanion on carbonyl

Since the carbonyl is sterically hindered, it would be much preferred to eliminate a hydride which then attacks the carbonyl. This gives 2 stable products.


Which one would be more preferred over the other and why?
Note: Source of carbanion is grignard.
P.S. I couldn't find any free to use reaction mechanism drawing software. Bear with the crappy drawing.

Not much chance of 1) happening, but you absolutely should include what's the source of supposed "carbanion". BTW there's plenty of free drawing software.

I think grignard would make sense. Didn't really think that would be too important. Will add it now. Also I tried MarvinJS Demo and something else too (both web apps) and one didn't have reaction arrows and one didn't position them properly. Mind linking any?

https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3245/how-to-draw-structures-of-compounds-while-writing-questions

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/37303/resources-for-learning-chemistry/

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/148121/does-%ce%b2-hydride-elimination-in-main-group-metals-occur

H- elimination is really unlikely

There are no carbanions in a Gringnard. For mechanisms you should always include all traction conditions.

@Martin-マーチン. This started off as more of a thought experiment between me and my friend as what would be the preferred method of attack. Please lmk what would be the appropriate reaction conditions for such a reaction and I would update it. Also isn't RMgX in the form of R(-)Mg(+)X?

I don't know about conditions for such a reaction. The mechanism for Grignard is studied extensively, and it's not what you propose. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grignard_reaction I really doubt there are any plausible mechanisms where there are free carbanions involved.

I think it would go through single electron transfer, not hydride transfer. By supposed "carbanion" I meant there's practically no such carbanion, like Mart says. While they exist, in a compound, the charge would have to be heavily delocalised.

@Mithoron. do you mind explaining the single electron transfer mechanism or recommending a source where I can read about it?

I dont think either of the reaction will occur. Reaction 2 definitely will not take place as in case of grignard you dont get self elimination products
